# Erro 500 ao consumir NFeDistribuicaoDFe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, web-service, nfe

Estou tentando consumir o serviço de download de NFE na fazenda:

https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx

Especificação

http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=2Z%20kcHOdpHs=

Usando
.Net, C#, MVC

mas tenho obtido o seguinte erro :

O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor.

A mensagem que tenho enviado é :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDistDFeInteresse>
            <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
                <distDFeInt versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
                    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                    <cUFAutor>31</cUFAutor>
                    <CNPJ>[CNPJ DA EMPRESA]</CNPJ>
                    <distNSU>
                        <ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>
                    </distNSU>
                </distDFeInt>
            </nfeDadosMsg>
        </nfeDistDFeInteresse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

REMOVI todos os espaços, consumo outros serviços com sucesso

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
```

O certificado tenho certeza que está correto também.

Ressalto que consigo consumir outros serviços.

WSDL do serviço

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
<s:element name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nfeDadosMsg">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="nfeDistDFeInteresseResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nfeDistDFeInteresseResult">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
<wsdl:input message="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap" type="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12" type="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
<wsdl:port name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap" binding="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
<soap:address location="https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12" binding="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12">
<soap12:address location="https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Recomendação: Efetuar testes na url do ambiente de homologação do serviço 
[NFeDistribuicaoDFe](https://hom.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx)

https://hom.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx

Segue abaixo xml válido para consulta desejada:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
<soap:Body>
    <nfeDistDFeInteresse>
        <nfeDadosMsg>
            <distDFeInt versao="1.00"
                xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <cUFAutor>31</cUFAutor>
                <CNPJ>[cnpj]</CNPJ>
                <distNSU>
                    <ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>
                </distNSU>
            </distDFeInt>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </nfeDistDFeInteresse>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta, usei exatamente o seu XML(substituindo o CNPJ claro), no ambiente de homologação e mesmo assim não funcionou. 
Até a pouco tempo este serviço funcionava aqui, mas parece que simplesmente começou esse erro.

Comment: Eu testei esse xml. Está funcionando. Será que você está tentando algum outro erro relacionado ao certificado?

Comment: Você conhece a ferramenta SoapUI? Com o SoapUI você conseguiria configurar o certificado e realizar teste de conexão com da url e testes do xml.

Answer (score 0):

seguindo esse tutorial fiz classe abaixo esses dias ta funcionando
http://pmarco777.blogspot.com.br/2015/01/download-da-nota-fiscal-eletronica-nfe.html

```
/// <summary>
        /// Classe download NFe versaodados 3.10
        /// </summary>
        public class NFe
        {
            private string _serialCertificado;
            private RecepcaoEvento.RecepcaoEventoSoapClient _nfeRecepcao;
            private NfeDownload.NfeDownloadNFSoapClient _nfeDonwload;
            private string[] chaveAcesso;
            private string cnpj;
            private string codigoUf;
            private string path;

            public NFe(string[] chaveAcesso, string cnpj, string codigoUf, string path)
            {
                _nfeRecepcao = new RecepcaoEvento.RecepcaoEventoSoapClient();
                _nfeDonwload = new NfeDownload.NfeDownloadNFSoapClient();
                this.chaveAcesso = chaveAcesso;
                this.path = path;
                this.codigoUf = codigoUf;
                this.cnpj = cnpj;
            }

            public void ConsultaNfe()
            {
                _nfeRecepcao.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, GetSerialCertificado());
                var xml = MontarXmlConsulta(chaveAcesso);
                var nfeCab = new RecepcaoEvento.nfeCabecMsg() { cUF = codigoUf, versaoDados = "1.00" };
                var resp = _nfeRecepcao.nfeRecepcaoEvento(nfeCab, xml);
                var fileResp = path + chaveAcesso[0] + ".xml";
                var fileReq = path + chaveAcesso[0] + ".xml";
                File.WriteAllText(fileReq, xml.OuterXml);
                File.WriteAllText(fileResp, resp.OuterXml);
                DownloadNFE();
            }

            public void DownloadNFE()
            {
                var xml = MontarXmlDownload(chaveAcesso);
                var NFe_Cab = new NfeDownload.nfeCabecMsg() { cUF = codigoUf, versaoDados = "1.00" };
                var fileResp = path + chaveAcesso[0] + ".xml";
                var fileReq = path + chaveAcesso[0] + ".xml";
                _nfeDonwload.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, GetSerialCertificado());
                var resp = _nfeDonwload.nfeDownloadNF(NFe_Cab, xml);
                File.WriteAllText(fileReq, xml.OuterXml);
                File.WriteAllText(fileResp, resp.OuterXml);
                //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileReq);
                //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileResp);
                AlterarSchemaXml();

            }


            private XmlDocument MontarXmlConsulta(string[] chaveAcesso)
            {
                var sbXml = new StringBuilder();
                sbXml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                    <envEvento xmlns=""http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"" versao=""1.00"">
                    <idLote>1</idLote>
                    ");
                foreach (var nota in chaveAcesso)
                {
                    sbXml.Append(@"
                    <evento xmlns=""http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"" versao=""1.00"">
                    <infEvento Id=""ID210210" + nota + @"01"">
                    <cOrgao>91</cOrgao>
                    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                    <CNPJ>" + cnpj + @"</CNPJ>
                    <chNFe>" + nota + @"</chNFe>
                    <dhEvento>" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + @"-03:00</dhEvento>
                    <tpEvento>210210</tpEvento>
                    <nSeqEvento>1</nSeqEvento>
                    <verEvento>1.00</verEvento>
                    <detEvento versao=""1.00"">
                    <descEvento>Ciencia da Operacao</descEvento>
                    </detEvento>
                    </infEvento>
                    </evento>
                    ");
                }
                sbXml.Append("</envEvento>");

                var xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(sbXml.ToString());

                var i = 0;
                foreach (var nota in chaveAcesso)
                {
                    var docXML = new SignedXml(xml);
                    docXML.SigningKey = _nfeRecepcao.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.PrivateKey;
                    var refer = new Reference();
                    refer.Uri = "#ID210210" + nota + "01";
                    refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
                    refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
                    docXML.AddReference(refer);
                    var ki = new KeyInfo();
                    ki.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(_nfeRecepcao.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate));
                    docXML.KeyInfo = ki;
                    docXML.ComputeSignature();
                    i++;
                    xml.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].AppendChild(xml.ImportNode(docXML.GetXml(), true));
                }
                return xml;
            }

            private XmlDocument MontarXmlDownload(string[] chaveAcesso)
            {
                var sbXml = new StringBuilder();
                sbXml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                <downloadNFe xmlns=""http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"" versao=""1.00"">
                <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                <xServ>DOWNLOAD NFE</xServ>
                <CNPJ>" + cnpj + @"</CNPJ>
                ");

                foreach (var nota in chaveAcesso)
                {
                    sbXml.Append("<chNFe>" + nota + "</chNFe>");
                }
                sbXml.Append("</downloadNFe>");
                var xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(sbXml.ToString());
                return xml;
            }

            private string GetSerialCertificado()
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store("My");
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                foreach (var certificado in store.Certificates)
                {
                    if (certificado.SubjectName.Name.Contains(cnpj))
                    {
                        _serialCertificado = certificado.SerialNumber;
                    }
                }
                store.Close();
                return _serialCertificado;
            }
        }
```